# AngularJS View does not show up while loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a simple view which takes 2 seconds to load.
I also have a loading overlay which checks the $http.pendingRequests to display a Loading-Overlay.

First the Overlay shows up, does it's thing and then the View pops in.
I need the View to be displayed BEFORE it has finished loading, so that the Overlay can actually be overlaid.

Help pls :(

**UPDATE: Controller.js code**

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("myApp")
    .controller("SearchController", SearchController);

SearchController.$inject = ["$state", "$stateParams", "$scope", "$rootScope", "$searchCache", "fswConvert", "fswAjaxPostPlain", "fswAjaxPost", "runtimeProvider"];

function SearchController($state, $stateParams, $scope, $rootScope, $searchCache, fswConvert, fswAjaxPostPlain, fswAjaxPost, runtimeProvider) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.ShowSearchResult = false;

        vm.init = function () {
            // Set page-size before processing the form to avoid multiple read events.
            var cachePageSize = $searchCache.get("PageSize");
            var currentPageSize = $("#SearchResultGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize();
            if (cachePageSize && cachePageSize !== currentPageSize) {
                $("#SearchResultGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize($searchCache.get("PageSize"));
            }

            if ($searchCache.get("LastSearch")) {

                var lastSearch = $searchCache.get("LastSearch");
                $("#Nachname").val(lastSearch.Nachname);
                $("#Vorname").val(lastSearch.Vorname);
                $("#Geburtsdatum").data("kendoDatePicker").value(lastSearch.Geburtsdatum);
                $("#SvnrTyp").data("kendoDropDownList").value(lastSearch.SvnrTyp);
                $("#Sozialversicherungsnummer").data("kendoMaskedTextBox").value(lastSearch.Sozialversicherungsnummer);
                $("#Kundennummer").data("kendoMaskedTextBox").value(lastSearch.Kundennummer);
                $("#Verstorben").prop("checked", lastSearch.Verstorben);
                $("#PhoneticSearch").prop("checked", lastSearch.PhoneticSearch);
                $("#PostleitzahlSearch").prop("checked", lastSearch.PostleitzahlSearch);
                $("#PostleitzahlValue").val(lastSearch.PostleitzahlValue);

                vm.processForm();
            }
        };

        vm.reset = function () {
            $searchCache.remove("LastSearch");
            $state.go("search", {}, { reload: true });
        };

        vm.showKendoValidationErrors = function () {
            var validatable = $("#SearchForm").data("kendoValidator");

            if (validatable.errors()) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    $rootScope.errors = validatable.errors();
                });
            }
            else {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    $rootScope.errors = [];
                });
            }
        };
        vm.hasFilter = function () {
            var nachname = $("#Nachname").val();
            var vorname = $("#Vorname").val();
            var geburtsdatum = $("#Geburtsdatum").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
            var svnrTyp = $("#SvnrTyp").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
            var sozialversicherungsnummer = $("#Sozialversicherungsnummer").data("kendoMaskedTextBox").value();
            var kundennummer = $("#Kundennummer").data("kendoMaskedTextBox").value();
            var plz = $("#PostleitzahlValue").val();

            return (nachname
                || vorname
                || geburtsdatum
                || (svnrTyp && svnrTyp !== 1)
                || sozialversicherungsnummer
                || kundennummer
                || plz);
        };

        vm.getSearchData = function (forGet) {
            var result = {
                Nachname: $("#Nachname").val(),
                Vorname: $("#Vorname").val(),
                SvnrTyp: $("#SvnrTyp").data("kendoDropDownList").value(),
                Sozialversicherungsnummer: $("#Sozialversicherungsnummer").data("kendoMaskedTextBox").raw(),
                Kundennummer: $("#Kundennummer").data("kendoMaskedTextBox").raw(),
                Verstorben: $("#Verstorben").is(":checked"),
                PhoneticSearch: $("#PhoneticSearch").is(":checked"),
                PostleitzahlSearch: $("#PostleitzahlSearch").is(":checked"),
                PostleitzahlValue: $("#PostleitzahlValue").val()
            };

            if (forGet) {
                if ($("#Geburtsdatum").data("kendoDatePicker").value()) {
                    result.Geburtsdatum = fswConvert.fswDateConvert("#Geburtsdatum");
                }
                else {
                    result.Geburtsdatum = null;
                }
            }
            else {
                result.Geburtsdatum = $("#Geburtsdatum").val();
            }
            return result;
        };

        vm.processForm = function () {
            if (vm.hasFilter()) {
                vm.ShowSearchResult = true;

                var grid = $("#SearchResultGrid").data("kendoGrid");

                grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = runtimeProvider.BaseUrl + "/Search/SearchResultRead";
                grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.data = vm.getSearchData(false);
                grid.dataSource.page(1);

                $searchCache.put("LastSearch", vm.getSearchData());
            }
            else {
                $rootScope.errors = ["Es muss zumindest ein Suchkriterium ausgefüllt sein um die Suche zu starten."];
            }
        };

        vm.processFormCreate = function (htmlPart) {
            $state.go("create", { searchParams: vm.getSearchData(true) });
        };

        vm.openPersonOverview = function (personId) {
            $state.go("person.overview", { personId: personId });
        };

        vm.cachePageSize = function () {
            var pageSize = $("#SearchResultGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize();
            $searchCache.put("PageSize", pageSize);
        };


        vm.init();
    }

})();
```

**Controller.cs code:**

```
{
    [AuthorizeRead]
    [NoCache]
    public class SearchController : BasePersonController
    {
        #region Properties.

        private const int ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 10;

        #endregion

        #region Search Actions.

        [HttpGet]
        [NoCache]
        public ActionResult KundInnenViaExternal(string hookBack)
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

            ViewBag.ActiveSubPage = hookBack.DecodeAsUrlParameter(); //for Toolbar

            return View("Search", new PersonSearchModel() {ExternalHook = ViewBag.ActiveSubPage});
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult KundInnen()
        {
            return View("Search");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AjaxOnly]
        [NoCache]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult KundInnen(PersonSearchModel model)
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ExternalHook))
                ViewBag.ActiveSubPage = model.ExternalHook; //for Toolbar

            if (!model.HasFilters)
                ModelState.AddModelError("NoFilters", "Es muss zumindest ein Suchkriterium ausgefüllt sein um die Suche zu starten.");

            return BuildJsonPostResult("Search", model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AjaxOnly]
        [HandleKendoError]
        public ActionResult SearchResultRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, PersonSearchModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid || model == null || !model.HasFilters)
                return null;

            model.IncludePersonFunktion = Enum.GetValues(typeof (EPersonFunktionType)).Cast<EPersonFunktionType>().Where(x => x != EPersonFunktionType.SachwalterProfessionell && x != EPersonFunktionType.VertreterInProfessionell).ToList();

            PersonSearchResultModel searchResult = PerformSearch(request, model, request.PageSize);

            return Json(new DataSourceResult
            {
                Data = searchResult.Personen,
                Total = searchResult.TotalAmount
            });
        }

        #endregion

        #region Create Actions.

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CreateKunde(PersonSearchModel model)
        {
            var createModel = new PersonCreateModel
            {
                Vorname = model.Vorname,
                Nachname = model.Nachname,
                DefaultSozialversicherungsnummer = new Sozialversicherungsnummer { Svnr = model.Sozialversicherungsnummer },
                AdditionalSozialversicherungsnummern = new List<Sozialversicherungsnummer> { new Sozialversicherungsnummer { SvnrTyp = ESvnrTyp.Auslaendisch } },
                Geburtsdatum = model.Geburtsdatum,
                GeburtslandOesterreich = CollectionCommands.GetGeburtslandOesterreich().Id,
                Funktion = EPersonFunktionType.Kunde,
            };
            createModel.Staatsbuergerschaft = new StaatsbuergerschaftModel();
            createModel.Staatsbuergerschaft.Aufenthaltsstatus = new AufenthaltsstatusModel();
            createModel.Staatsbuergerschaft.Aufenthaltsstatus.AufenthaltUnbefristet =
                CollectionCommands.GetAufenthaltstitelUnbefristet().ToList();

            return PartialView("../Person/Create", createModel);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Abstract methods implementation.

        protected override ActionResult ExecuteWriteCreatePerson(PersonCreateModel model)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Das Erzeugen einer Person wird nicht über den \"SearchController\" bereitgestellt.");
        }

        protected override ActionResult ExecuteWriteUpdatePerson(PersonUpdateModel model)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Das Bearbeiten einer Person wird nicht über den \"SearchController\" bereitgestellt.");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really important to provide code to accompany your question, otherwise people will simply be guessing at solutions. For example, are you using `ng-init();` in your view?

Comment: No, we don't use it. Sorry I'm new to angular and don't even know which code is useful to post here. I've got a Navbar which I load with `@Html.Partial` which shows up as soon as the page loads. My View then get's loaded in a div with "ui-view" and with `@RenderBody`

Comment: If you are calling apis in resolve of angular state, then view will be loaded only after resolve is complete. So you need to move the api calls from resolve to corresponding page controller.

Comment: Post code in your question, not comments. An angular view will contain things such as `ng-repeat` and `ng-model`. The controller that you are using is also required in order to properly answer the question. Google these things if you are unsure what they may look like.

Comment: Alright guys thanks for your patience, I updated my question with the controller code

Comment: Take a closer look at @PaulsonPeter's comment, that's your answer.